# What scheme will allow merging and splitting the result of a function?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, proxy-re-encryption

I am wondering if it's possible to have a scheme as follows.

Here is the scenario:

- we have a set of objects (e.g. strings) {O1, O2, ..., On}
- we have a set of users {U1, U2, ..., Um}
- each user asks to compute a special function f over a subset of the objects
- we have an intermediate (trusted) component A that must be able to merge requests coming from different users into one single request
- we have a third (untrusted) component B that computes f over the objects contained in the request sent by A
- A must be able to split/derive the result of the function for the request of each user

I am looking for a function f that would satisfy this scheme

All requests and results should be encrypted and no key is shared among users.

A is trusted. B is NOT trusted.

By merge I mean that the resulting request should be a request to compute the union of all the subsets contained in the users' requests.

B must not know which request came from which user.

This scheme does not need to be able to handle arbitrary functions.

Here is a practical example:

There are three users U1, U2 and U3 and a set of objects {O1, O2, O3, O4, O5}

- U1 requests to compute f(O1, O2)
- U2 requests to compute f(O1,O2,O3)
- U3 requests to compute f(O1,O4,O5)
- A receives these three requests and creates a new request to compute f(O1,O2,O3,O4,O5) which is the union of the requests sent by users.
- B computes f(O1,O2,O3,O4,O5)
- A receives f(O1,O2,O3,O4,O5) and somehow is able to derive f(O1, O2) for U1, f(O1,O2,O3) for U2 and f(O1,O4,O5) for U3

Is there any scheme which will allow me to achieve what I explained above?

Comment: Are A,B or the server trusted?

Comment: @user8911 A is trusted. B is NOT trusted.

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Or what is the security goal of the merge? So that B doesn't know which request came from which user?

Comment: Does this need to be able to handle arbitrary functions? $\;$

Comment: @mikeazo by merge I mean that the resulting request should be a request to compute the union of all the subsets contained in the users' requests. Right, B must not know which request came from which user.

Comment: @RickyDemer this does not need to be able to handle arbitrary functions.

Comment: it seems that your question is about  [Private Information Retrieval](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.9441&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @Alex I don't think PIR is the answer to my problem. How would it allow me to merge and split the result of the function? Moreover, there is no problem if B knows which objects are requested by A. The only thing I want to hide is which user requested which object.

Comment: Could you give a simple concrete example of what you are looking for but w/o any crypto? I'm still just having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: @mikeazo I added a practical example. Is it more clear now?

Comment: "This does not need to be able to handle arbitrary functions" - then what sort of functions does it need to be able to handle? For many functions, there is no such scheme as you require, unless perhaps B computes every possibly combination of inputs and passes back to A. This would obfuscate which combos of inputs were requested, and by who; but the complexity of calculating all those results would soon ramp up.

Comment: @occulus f must not be ANY function. What I am looking for is a special function f which allows me to do what explained above.

Comment: Oh, I see. You should make this clear in your question. At the end of your question you need to say "I am looking for a function f that would satisfy this scheme".

Comment: But your question says "each user asks to compute a function" which makes it sound like an arbitrary function. I think you need to rephrase your question slightly, it's confusing at the moment. What's the point of users asking to compute a function if it's a function limited to be what will work with this scheme?